# If we had a good enough eyesight would we be able to see atoms and the fuzziness of the quantum world?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength, vision

If our eyes had enough precision and calibration to see hundreds of thousands smaller scales than we do, surely our brains would also need a major tuneup to process it. But could our classical body technically ever be able to see the atoms or any part of the discrete  quantum world.

Comment: We do have detectors to “see” the quantum world. So if your eyesight worked on that principle, yes.

Answer (score -1):

If something like that happens it will be a great thing for the humankind. But still with upmost precision and calibration our eyes would not be able to see atoms or any part of discrete quantum world, because even the strongest microscope ever made by humans is still not able to detect the picture of atom perfectly, but it will also not work because we require light to see something, the light gets reflected by the object which i am seeing and as a reason i am able to see the object, but the atoms are so small that light does not interacts with it.

Comment: I am not the down voter but    "but the atoms are so small that light does not interacts with it." this is not correct. Electromagnetic waves have a large spectrum and atoms do interact with electromagnetic waves,